# max function for the current time

Tags: r, date, posixct

How do I create a column with the current high of the day following the time? I used pmax but it wasn't helpful.

```
> df
             date_time  Price
1 2018-02-01 18:13:17 3178.5
2 2018-02-01 18:13:13 3179.0
3 2018-02-01 18:13:13 3178.5
4 2018-02-01 18:13:13 3178.5
5 2018-02-01 18:13:09 3178.5
6 2018-02-01 18:13:00 3178.5
7 2018-02-01 18:12:54 3179.5
8 2018-02-01 18:12:43 3179.5
```

I'm trying to do this.

```
> mutate(df, high_day = ?)
            date_time  Price high_day
1 2018-02-01 18:13:17 3179.5   3179.5
2 2018-02-01 18:13:13 3179.0   3179.0
3 2018-02-01 18:13:13 3178.5   3179.0
4 2018-02-01 18:13:13 3179.0   3179.0
5 2018-02-01 18:13:09 3178.5   3178.5
6 2018-02-01 18:13:00 3178.5   3178.5
7 2018-02-01 18:12:54 3178.5   3178.5
8 2018-02-01 18:12:43 3178.5   3178.5
```

for reproduction:

```
structure(list(data_hora = structure(c(1517508797, 1517508793, 
1517508793, 1517508793, 1517508789, 1517508780, 1517508774, 1517508763, 
1517508763, 1517508763, 1517508763, 1517508757, 1517508756), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Preco = c(3178.5, 3179, 3178.5, 3178.5, 
3178.5, 3178.5, 3179.5, 3179.5, 3179.5, 3179.5, 3179, 3179, 3179.5
)), row.names = 38:50, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is this a group_by(date_time) %>% mutate(max)

Comment: I got nothing! I need the current max and I still can't manage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How's this:

```
library(lubridate)
df %>%
  arrange(date_time) %>%
  group_by(date = as.Date(date_time)) %>%
  mutate(day_high = cummax(Price))
```

Comment: It is still has couple issues. One of the can be: What if we had duplicated rows for the same date with different price, the same max should be reported for all of them but your solution does not take care of that.

Comment: To make it robust maybe this would be better: ```df1 %>%
  group_by(data_hora) %>% 
  mutate(max_price = max(Preco)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(data_hora) %>% 
  group_by(date = as.Date(data_hora)) %>% 
  mutate(day_high = cummax(max_price))```

Comment: That does something different, and I'm not sure it's what OP wants.